# How to host a HTML site on WordPress without using any theme? Is that Possible?

Tags: wordpress

I want to host my HTML coded site (it's just HTML) on WordPress without any themes, is that possible? To remove the theme but still use WordPress to host and access the HTML pages, how would that be done? Where would I paste the HTML then if I remove the theme?

I also noticed when I try to remove the themes manually, it collapses WordPress and I can't access the WP-admin control panel. So how do I keep WordPress instated and accessible without a theme installed on it?

Please see this quick 1:50 second video: http://youtu.be/5Jd_KV3p5Kw (it shows a demo of it)

Comment: Please don't repost your question: [Anyone Good with Wordpress? Got a ?? with video explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16128647)

Comment: can u explain why u used wordpress for static site

Comment: I deleted the last question since it got a bunch of minus votes. Im using wordpress because  I would still like to use wordpress plugins, And be able to use the wordpress control panel to access the site.  But i want to get rid of the other pages

Comment: The other question was at -5 and arguably beyond salvaging. I'd have posted a new question, too. (the short answer still is: yes, you need to have a theme)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress requires you use a theme. As such, there's no *good* reason to try and remove the themeing functionality.

However, it sounds like you want to integrate a static HTML page in lieu of your standard dynamically generated WordPress page which uses the WYSIWYG editor and functions. Simply modifying the "`home.php`" or "`index.php`" should change how the home page is displayed. Essentially, you can paste all your normal HTML in there without using WordPress's dynamic functionality. You can also generate pages in WordPress's backend, and customize the HTML for the individual pages by creating files in your active theme folder called `page-{slug}.php`, where slug is the slug of the page you'd like to control. From there, you can use WordPress's *shortcodes* to display various plugin data, should the plugin(s) support shortcodes (you can always program them yourself).

WordPress tries to simplify the development experience by preparing a series of pre-built functions which helps you *avoid repeating yourself*. From what it sounds like, you want to skip past most of the WordPress magic and defeat a lot of the purposes of having WordPress to only utilize *some* WordPress plugin functionality.

1. Customize the `index.php`, `page-{slug}.php`, `404.php`, `header.php`, and `footer.php` pages in your active theme folder and strip out any WordPress functionality. *Note: I don't see the benefit in this other than lack of knowledge in WordPress theme integrations*.
2. Use `do_shortcode` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode to call plugin functions directly *outside the loop* without the need of rendering a page's WYSIWYG content.

While it might be more of an effort, it's worth it in the long run to spend a few hours learning the basics of WordPress HTML -> Theme integrations. Not only is it a valuable skill (you're practically already on-route already), but it'll save you time later that otherwise could've been avoided. The knowledge will pay for itself.

I hope that helped.

Comment: I sort of did that, I used index.php to paste my html in and it worked as my homepage, but the issues now is that there is still all the other wordpress files like comments.php, 404.php, etc... and they show up when you miss-spell a url, it shows the theme. I also want to be able to add new pages like domain.com/about and make it JUST out of HTML as i did for the homepage with index.php, but I want to add other pages like that, how do I do that? And remove all the other unused crud?

Comment: Modify the `404.php` and paste in your 404 HTML code. Literally, just the entire <html></html> code if you really are bent on a purely static page. If you want a pure HTML page for a specific page, (e.g. about page), then make a page called "About" in the backend and create a new file called `page_about.php` in your theme folder and paste your pure raw <html></html> about page code there. That's all there is to it.

Comment: lol Im close. So I went into my webhosts file manager, created a file called "page_about" with the extension of PHP, and found the file in wordpress control panel, but I dont know how I assign that file to be the url of "domain.com/about"  ?

Comment: Ah, one small change. Looks like it's `page-{slug}.php` instead of `page_{slug}.php`.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates Just rename the file to `page-about.php` and it should *automatically* detect it, and set it to be the page template file.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! HOLY FRICKEN TACO BELL COW! THANK YOU, YOU MADE MY NIGHT. Im an idiot with this stuff and did not think I would be able to figure out what your talking about, but it worked perfect! That is a very easy way to create static pages, just add a file called "page-{slug}.php"  in file manager. Great to know! THANKS!